# Hyperledger composer TypeError: Cannot create property 'wallet' on string 'resumedevelop'

Tags: node.js, events, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, subscribe

I want to subscribe event.
so I make a event.js File

### event.js

```
'use strict';


const BusinessNetworkConnection = require('composer-client').BusinessNetworkConnection;
const winston = require('winston');
var chalk = require('chalk');
let config = require('config').get('event-app');
let participantId = config.get('participantId');
let participantPwd = config.get('participantPwd');
const LOG = winston.loggers.get('application');

var connection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();
return connection.connect('admin@resumedevelop', 'resumedevelop', 'admin', 'adminpw')
    .then(function (definition) {
        // Retrieved Business Network Definition
        console.log(definition === connection.getBusinessNetwork());  // true
    });
```

---

`"resumedevelop"` is networkName

I run a BusinessNetwork 
and attempt to 
command "node event.js"

as a result,

```
(node:28771) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot create property 'wallet' on string 'resumedevelop'
```

please give me advice.. !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the API reference for [BusinessNetworkConnection](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/api/client-businessnetworkconnection#connect) I would say that the error is telling you that you are passing a string as the 2nd parameter when an object is expected.

But I would also observe that the Network name, and Credentials (or more likely certificates) are part of the Business Network Card that you are supplying as the first parameter, so you don't need to specify those extra parameters.